# Convert benzene to isopropylbenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, aromatic-compounds

> Which of the following reagents will convert benzene to isopropylbenzene? Choose all that are appropriate.
>
> [image]

I know for certain that (b) can be used, but I also think the following mechanism with (d) is also possible:

[image]

Is my line of thinking correct with this one?

Answer (score 5):

You are right, both abstracting $\ce{Cl-}$ from the alkyl chloride with Lewis acid as well as dehydration of isopropanol with $\ce{H2SO4}$ are suitable ways to generate the 2-propyl carbocation, your electrophile in this reaction. Option (c) will not work because $\ce{AlCl3}$ reacts with alcohols to form aluminium alkoxides.

**Source**: [Master Organic Chemisry](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/07/22/reagent-friday-aluminum-chloride-alcl3/)

Comment: Out of curiosity: wouldn't d) produce a significant amount of $\ce{PhSO3H}$ ?